# Inserting value in table with the click of a button

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a file called `test.php`.

What I'm trying to do is, to insert a value into a table by clicking a submit button

I have two tables, `tbl_1` and `tbl_2`

`tbl_1`

```
id | name | age


4  | john |  20

9  | tim  |  25

8  | lea  |  22
```

While tbl_2 have the same structure as `tbl_1`, it is empty or without any value in it... the idea is that I want to have a button, after clicking on that button, it will insert the value of `tbl_1` into `tbl_2` based on the id

The question is, how do I fill in `tbl_2` with the value of `tbl_1`, through a click of a submit button?

I made a form, trying to bring the value from `tbl_1` to `tbl_2`, but to no avail...

```
 <form action="test.php?id" method="post">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="submit" value="Copy"/>
</form>

 <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $io = $_POST['io'];
     $no_kes = $_POST['no_kes'];
     $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_2(name, age) VALUES ( '".$name."', '".$age."')";
     $result = mysql_query($SQL);
}
?>
```

Below is how my table looks like on the web.

[image]

Below is the code for the table I constructed.

```
           <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>

      <th></th>
    </tr>
  <?php
  // Read
  $per_page = 7;
  if (isset($_GET["page"]))
    $page = $_GET["page"];
  else
    $page = 1;
  $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;


  $sql = "select * from tbl_1";
  $result = $mydb->query($sql);
  while ($readrow = $result->fetch_array()) {
  ?>   
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $readrow['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $readrow['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $readrow['age']; ?></td>
     <td>
```

Comment: How are you constructing this HTML table? Include all the relevant HTML and PHP code as well.

Comment: Where is the form from where you are getting the name and age?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul done

Comment: @Exprator done.

Comment: @abcd I've given an answer below, hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of things you need to change in your code, such as:

- You need to change your form's `action` attribute in the following way,

  ```
  <form action="test.php?id=<?php echo $readrow['id']; ?>" method="post">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" name="submit" value="Copy"/>
  </form>
  ```
- Subsequently, you have to catch a particular row's id in *test.php* page the following way,

  ```
  $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
  ```
- Finally perform your `INSERT` operation in the following way,

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $SQL = "INSERT INTO tbl_2(name, age) SELECT name, age FROM tbl_1 WHERE id = {$id}";
      $result = mysql_query($SQL);
  }
  ```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: @abcd Glad I could help. Cheers! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already mentioned tbl_2 has the same structure as tbl_1, you may simply construct your DB query as:

```
insert into tbl_2(id, name, age) select tbl_1.id, tbl_1.name, tbl_1.age from tbl_1 left join tbl_2 on tbl_1.id = tbl_2.id;
```

What this does:

> It scans tbl_1 and inserts any values that are missing in
>   tbl_2 table. It has the potential to insert duplicate values. For
>   that, you should have enough robust DB structure that avoids
>   duplicate values in a table (using unique keys etc).